# How to find names of variables on Unity components?

Tags: unity, c#

I’m trying to make a Distance Joint in Unity 2D. I have it set up and it works properly in the game. However, when I go to set the ‘Connected Rigid Body’ field through code, I can’t figure out what the actual variable name is to get a reference to it.

This is the variable I want to access through code:

[image]

I want to be able to set that property like this:

```
distanceJoint2D.[nameofproperty] = other.transform.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
```

Is there a way to figure out what the variable names associated with its components are?

Comment: Did you check [the scripting API documentation for this component](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/DistanceJoint2D.html)? It has a [rather obvious candidate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Joint2D-connectedBody.html) listed...

Comment: Thank you so very much for that! That was exactly what I needed. I had no idea that those docs existed.

Comment: Want to post an answer below showing how you solved your problem? And in future, be sure to search for documentation first. Any halfway decent tool or API will have something like this, and even when they're imperfect they're way better than guessing, and usually faster than asking here. 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @DMGregory for finding these docs: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ which have all of the components and the variables within them. The specific link to the Distance Joint 2D is here: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/DistanceJoint2D.html So with that, the completed code looks like this:

```
distanceJoint2D.connectedBody = other.transform.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
```